# UIButton not getting touches when added to self.view

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, touch, subview

I have this scheme which is working fine (`-->` = "has subview"):

```
ViewController.view --> imageView --> containerView --> UIButton
```

As expected, the button fires off the designated selector.
However, if I do the following (which for several reasons is preferable) the button **stops receiving touches**.

```
ViewController.view --> imageView
ViewController.view --> containerView --> UIButton
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_containerView];
```

Any leads?

-- UPDATE

Responding to requests, here is some button creation code:

```
// in viewDidLoad

_controlsView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Controls" 
       owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
_controlsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 
      _controlsView.bounds.size.width, _controlsView.bounds.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:_controlsView];
// ...
[_controlsView.superview bringSubviewToFront:_controlsView];

// in viewDidAppear

if (!_demoButton) {
   _demoButton = (UIButton*)[_controlsView viewWithTag:kDemoButtonTag];
   [_demoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   // configuration, color, font, layer, etc. all works well
}
```

Finally, the `Controls.xib` looks like this:

[image: Screenshot in IB]

Comment: Presumably you've tried setting "@property(nonatomic, getter=isUserInteractionEnabled) BOOL userInteractionEnabled" throughout the hierarchy?

Comment: @Ōkami Yes. All `userInteractionEnabled` are set. Otherwise, it the button would not work if added to image view, right?

Comment: @Mundi: are you adding button to imageView ?

Comment: No. I think the explanation above is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

`Probably` your view is ruling over your button.try with this

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:<UIButton_INSTANCE>];
```

Comment: Sorry. The button is a subview of the container view. As stated, it works well when the container view is added to the image view, which rules out this possibility.

Comment: yes that is clear from your question. That's why I mentioned probably in my answer , so that it could be the case. Did you try it once?

Comment: Sure. Both after creation and in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens, well has happened to me, when I have set a control element outside the frame of the container view. I've not tested this, but as you've got many nested views, it may occur on the first instance as the imageview may be large enough to encompass the UIButton.

Comment: The image view is indeed larger than the container view and the button. But it should be **behind** the container view. The button is certainly inside the container view, so that cannot be the reason either.

Comment: Hi, I just rebuilt your structure and couldn't replicate the problem. It all works as you're expecting it to work. If the UIButton is within the containers frame then the touches are registered.  Adding the container as a subview of the imageView made no difference.If you could post the view creation and subView adding code, perhaps there's something i've overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Due to not enough codes, it is impossible to precisely figure out the reason why this happened.

I suppose you should try to write a category of UIButton to overwrite `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` `-touchesMoved:withEvent:` `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` with some debug info output like:

```
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"Touches began/moved/ended!");
}
```

When you pressed the UIButton instance, and the debug info was get printed, that means your UIButton's instance has received touch events but not handled it in right way. And in the opposite, that means there is an instance in respond chain blocked the events delivery.

Particularly, if it is found that only touches began debug info get printed and touches moved debug info no longer get printed after your fingers moved, your touch events probably were blocked by a gesture recognizer.

Comment: I tried the `touchesBegan` method. It only catches the image view touches. The button does not get touches. Well, we knew that already. As stated above, the button is hooked up correctly and working as expected when its container is added as a subview to the image view.